# Query Para Retornar Registros mais Recentes Com Base Em Outra Tabela

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Bom dia Pessoal,

Queria a ajuda de vocês para entender parte de uma consulta que estou montando, com o pouco de conhecimento que tenho.

Antes de mais nada deixo aqui um modelo que criei no [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb91de/1/0) para ajudar a entender o que preciso.

Resumindo, basicamente tenho uma tabela que representa compressores dos clientes, e outra tabela que representa revisões feitas nesses equipamentos. O que preciso é de uma query que retorne as últimas avaliações feitas em cada compressor.

O que consegui até agora é o que está no Fiddle, tentei colocar um where com subquery agrupando pelo id da revisão, mas não consegui o resultado esperado.

Como podem ver, o compressor A tem 5 avaliações e o compressor B apenas 1. Precisava retornar a avaliação de ID 6 que é a última do compressor A e a avaliação 7 que é a única do compressor B.

Comment: Você precisa demonstrar o problema na própria pergunta (favor [edit]), em vez de postar esses links. Veja [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/74) e as [dicas sobre exemplo mínimo](/help/mcve). Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é uma subquery fazendo o MAX para a "chave" em questão.

Esta subselect pode gerar problemas de perfomance dependendo da falta de índices etc.

Se aplica mais a quando se quer obter o dados da maior/menor ocorrência de um evento pis o uso deMAX agrupado não garante isto.

Problema recorrente.

No subselect é preciso um alias para diferenciar as instâncias da chamada.

```
select
    evaluation.id as evaluationid,
    evaluation.evaluationdate,
    compressor.name as compressor
from evaluation
join customer on customer.id = evaluation.customerid
join customercompressor on customercompressor.id = evaluation.customercompressorid
join compressor on compressor.id = customercompressor.compressorid
and evaluation.evaluationdate = (select max(evaluation2.evaluationdate)
                                 From evaluation evaluation2
                                 Where evaluation2.customercompressorid = evaluation.customercompressorid)  
group by customercompressor.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb91de/3

Comment: É exatamente isso. Vou tentar assimilar a solução. Muito obrigado.